Make comment and reply layout flutter
Currently, I'm making a comment and reply layout for a blog flutter, the layout like the picture under. I know that the main item comment and item reply can be reuseable and of course, there's a listview to show comments and under comments there's a listview to show the reply comment, but I don't know how to apply them. Can you show me the way how to make it correctly.

To create a layout for comments and replies, it's a good approach to define each comment and reply as separate widgets. You can use ListView.builder to display both comments and replies. The main ListView will show the comments, and inside each comment widget, a nested ListView can be used to display the replies.
Key steps:

Create a main ListView.builder to display the comments, and for each
item, use a custom widget such as CommentItemWidget.
Inside CommentItemWidget, create another ListView.builder to display
the replies (ReplyItemWidget).
If you have too many replies and ListView.builder causes performance
issues, consider using alternatives like SingleChildScrollView and
Column.


ListView.builder(
  itemCount: comments.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final comment = comments[index];
    return CommentItemWidget(comment: comment);
  },
);

class CommentItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Comment comment;
  CommentItemWidget({required this.comment});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(comment.text),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true, // The ListView's height is adjusted according to its content.
          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Prevent nested ListView from scrolling independently.
          itemCount: comment.replies.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final reply = comment.replies[index];
            return ReplyItemWidget(reply: reply);
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


This structure can flexibly display both comments and replies. If you want to update the comments and replies dynamically, you might want to consider using a state management solution like StatefulWidget, Provider, Riverpod, or Bloc.

Thank you for your solution and I really appreciate it. I wonder that can I apply CommentItemWidget for reply item instead of ReplyItemWidget is it ok? Becase the UI of comment and reply are the same?

Yes, absolutely! If the UI for comments and replies is the same, you can definitely reuse CommentItemWidget for both. This approach would reduce redundant code and improve maintainability.
